# Подключение к VPS с активным VPN подключением

Tags: ubuntu, vps, vpn, wireguard

У меня есть VPS сервер с Ubuntu. На нем будет установлен сервер WireGuard, а также клиент ExpressVPN.

В момент активации клиента ExpressVPN поднимается tun0 и весь трафик проходит через него, исключая возможность подключения к серверу (SSH, HTTPS, WireGuard). Обычно подобное решал таблицей маршрутизации:

```
ip rule add table 128 from 45.82.14.88
ip route add table 128 to 45.82.14.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via 45.82.14.1
```

Но тут почему-то не прокатывает и сервер остается недоступен при активном VPN клиенте. Я в маршрутах практически профан и буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

Информация по интерфейсам и маршрутам до подключения:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           t qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:1d:da:64:31:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 45.82.14.88/24 brd 45.82.14.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86114sec preferred_lft 86114sec
    inet6 fe80::901d:daff:fe64:31a1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
default via 45.82.14.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 45.82.14.88 metric 100
45.82.14.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 45.82.14.88
169.254.169.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 45.82.14.88 metric 100
```

Информация по интерфейсам и маршрутам после подключения:

```
1:  lo: <L00P8ACK,UP,L0WER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000    
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2:  ethO: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq.codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:ld:da:64:31:al brd ff :ff :ff :ff :ff :ff
    inet 45.82.14.88/24 brd 45.82.14.255 scope global dynamic ethO
        valid_lft 85937sec preferred_lft 85937sec
3:  tunO: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 100.64.100.6 peer 100.64.100.5/32 scope global tunO
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 100.64.100.5 dev tunO
default via 45.82.14.1 dev ethO proto dhcp src 45.82.14.88 metric 100
10.0.0.0/8 via 45.82.14.1 dev ethO
45.82.14.0/24 dev ethO proto kernel scope link src 45.82.14.88
45.85.91.92 via 45.82.14.1 dev ethO
100.64.100.1 via 100.64.100.5 dev tunO
100.64.100.5 dev tunO proto kernel scope link src 100.64.100.6
128.0.0.0/1 via 100.64.100.5 dev tunO
169.254.169.0/24 dev ethO proto dhcp scope link src 45.82.14.88 metric 100
172.16.0.0/12 via 45.82.14.1 dev ethO
192.168.0.0/16 via 45.82.14.1 dev ethO
```